# Collection View cell text not showing my data and not showing my number of items in section properly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uicollectionview

Hello im doing to do app with firebase. I'm using collection view for show saved user task. When i fetch my tasks i see my fetch data at console properly. Nothing problem with that. I can get my data. But when i try to present my tasks at my collection view i see blank cells or i see random one or two tasks. When i try to add new task, for example i have total 7 task but my collection view have 12 cell. I'm saving one task but my collection view total cell have more than one.

As you can see down below image i have total 2 task saved at firebase but my collection view showing 6 cell. Also not present my tasks at cell text.

[image]

**So this is my how to save my task function.**

```
    @objc func addTaskButtonClicked() {
        
      
        if NewTaskViewController.textView.text == "" {
            
            makeAlert(titleInput: "Error", messageInput: "Please write your task.")
            
        }else {
            guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
            guard let text = NewTaskViewController.textView.text else {return}
            let taskId = NSUUID().uuidString
            let data = [
                "text" : text,
                "timestamp" : Timestamp(date: Date()),
                "taskId" : taskId,
            ] as [String : Any]
            Firestore.firestore().collection("tasks").document(currentUid).collection("ongoing_tasks").document(taskId).setData(data)
        //    NewTaskViewController.textView.text = ""
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

**This is my how to fetch data from firebase function.**

```
func fetchTasks(uid : String,completion : @escaping([Task])-> Void) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        var tasks = [Task]()
     
        Firestore.firestore().collection("tasks").document(uid).collection("ongoing_tasks").order(by: "timestamp").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
         
            if let err = error {
                
                print(err)
            }else {
                if let snapShotDocument = snapshot?.documents {
                    for doc in snapShotDocument {
                        let data = doc.data()
              
                        tasks.append(Task(data: data))
                        print(data)
                        print(tasks)
                       
                        completion(tasks)
                            TasksViewController.collectionView.reloadData()
                
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
      
    }
```

**This is my Task struct.**

```
struct Task {
    
    let tasksID : String
    let text : String
    let timestamp : Timestamp
    
    init(data : [String : Any]) {
        self.tasksID = data["taskId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.text = data["text"] as? String ?? ""
        self.timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())
    } 
}
```

I'm using two get set for user and task.

```
     var user : User? {
        didSet {
            configure()
            
        }
    }
```

```
  private func configure() {
        guard let user = self.user else {return}
        TasksViewController.nameLabel.text = "Hi \(user.name)"
        fetchTasks()
    }
```

```
    private func fetchTasks() {
        
        guard let uid = self.user?.uid else {return}
        print(uid)
        fetchTasks(uid: uid) { tasks in
            print(uid)
            TasksViewController.tasks = tasks
      
        }
    }
```

```
   var task : Task? {
        didSet {
            configure()
        }
    }
```

```
 private func configure() {
        guard let task = self.task else {return}
        TasksViewCell.textLabel.text = task.text
    }
```

And this is how to present my tasks at my collection view.

```
 static var tasks = [Task]()

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      
        return TasksViewController.tasks.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TasksViewController.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TasksViewCell
       cell.task = TasksViewController.tasks[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

So how can i solve this problem. Thanks for any help. Love y'all.

Comment: Check on the addTaskButtonClicked button click. print logs data dictionary and what text is going, I think the text is going ""(blank). check firestore database.

Comment: There is no empty task "" saved to Firebase or in my data.. Sometimes it saves a task twice but I don't understand why.

Comment: when the data is coming from addSnapshotListener, what is the dictionary value that comes from the listener?

Comment: What do you mean?